# Is there a where * like command in SQL

Tags: sql

The following does not work:

```
DECLARE @jake varchar(30); 
SET @jake='$%$^$%'

SELECT [PlayerID], [Nickname], [UserName], [ClubNumber], 
       [FirstName], [Email], [LastName], [DOB] 
FROM [Players] 
WHERE ***** LIKE'%'+@jake+'%' 
ORDER BY lastname ASC
```

I am trying to use the `*` for all columns so I do not have to list them all out using or commands. Any ideas?

Comment: This is T-SQL I presume?  There's no direct way to do this. You would have to query the information_schema database to get the columns, then build a dynamic SQL query to execute. I would advise against it and just be explicit about the columns you make use of in your queries.

Comment: If you are using MS SQL Server then in SQL Server Management Studio you can right click on a table in the object explorer, then pick `Script table as` -> `Select to` -> new window or clipboard.. this will save you a lot of typing, but you should be specific about the columns you use.. even if you intend on writing dynamic logic to change which columns are returned.. you should be using different `Views` instead for the cases where you want a different list of columns to be returned to keep things simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a wildcard for the column name, at least not in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. You'll have to spell out the fields you want to compare, though you CAN do it like

```
WHERE CONCAT(field1, field2, field3, ....) LIKE '%...%'
```

Since you're doing a true whilecard like `%...%`, this will work. If you were doing the other types (`LIKE '...%'` or `LIKE '%...'`), this wouldn't work.

Comment: Assuming he's using SQL Server **2012** or newer - earlier versions didn't have `CONCAT`